# HashMap ClassCastException String to MyClass

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, jira-plugin

I want to iterate over a HashMap.

```
public void setMyHashMap(final String key,
        final HashMap<Integer, MyClass> value) throws NullPointerException{
        settings.put(key, value);
}

public HashMap<Integer, MyClass> getMyHashMap(String key) {
    return (HashMap<Integer, MyClass>) settings.get(key);
}
------------------------------------------------------------
for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyClass> e : settings.getMyHashMap(key)
                                             .entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getValue());
}
```

This displays a reference to an object of MyClass like "MyClass@9d5f8e"

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyClass> e : settings.getMyHashMap()
                                             .entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getValue().getLabel());
}
```

But as soon as I want to access data of this object, it gets casted to MyClass, which should be ok but isn't. It seems as if the object is in fact a String as I get this Exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyClass

I don't get it.
I pass the HashMap several times and the SettingsClass casts the stored object to the HashMap without problems. If I print the value I get the reference to MyClass but as soon as I want to access data in it, the JRE thinks it's a String object.

Comment: `System.out.println(e.getValue().getClass());`?

Comment: show more about your code

Comment: Your `settings` map is probably having values of `HashMap<Integer, String>` type maps.

Comment: System.out.println(e.getValue().getClass()); does not work as it wants to cast first to MyClass and the same exceptions gets thrown. If there would be a String in my Map which really can´t as there is only one method to store MyClass in it wouldn't it just throw an exception at this point which it doesn't.

Comment: please post the part where you `put` the values in the `HashMap`

Comment: which type of code u want? there's just my setSettings which could be important

Comment: Problem may be in your MyClass not the map, show the code for it

Comment: MyClass is very simple, 3 private variables with simple get and set methods, nothing more.

Comment: In your method call getMyHashMap() you do not use a string parameter which you should. Can you save 'e' to variable and check what type of variable you really get when you iterate over entrySet()?

Comment: Typing mistake. I don't know if I get your idea right milez, but saving e in a variable does not work because it gets casted which doesn't work...

Comment: Save it to Object, everything in java inherits from Object (it is also posssible, in fact very likely, that I just dont get it)

Comment: I can store e in Object,casting backwards does work too. But again if I want to access data I get the exception. I'm so confused why this doesn't work.

Comment: It seems the settings-library of jira only supports Strings in its Lists and Maps...  How could you know this, I feel stupid.

Comment: What, specifically, is "settings"? If this is a bean in JIRA itself or in SAL that you are trying to use to persist an object, remember that the lifecycle of your plugin (and hence the lifecycle of your classes) is independent of any storage that JIRA uses. For example, you can store an object and then uninstall your plugin. MyClass goes poof, but the obj is still stored. The upshot of this is that you are generally restricted to using JRE classes and JIRA-native classes for anything you ask JIRA itself to persist. (If you need to store your own objects, serialize them to XML first.)

Comment: I use SAL Plugin Settings.  Thanks Scott for the explanation why I can't store MyClass in this settings. If I had thought about this I may have found out about by myself...  I think I will make JSON-Strings to store my Object in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work - I just tried it out:

```
class MyClass {
    public String foo;
    public String bar;

    public String getLabel() {
        return "foo: " + foo + ", bar: " + bar;
    }
}

MyClass myObj1 = new MyClass();
myObj1.foo = "foo1";
myObj1.bar = "bar1";

MyClass myObj2 = new MyClass();
myObj2.foo = "foo2";
myObj2.bar = "bar2";

java.util.Map<Integer, MyClass> myHashMap = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, MyClass>();
myHashMap.put(1, myObj1);
myHashMap.put(2, myObj2);

for (java.util.Map.Entry<Integer, MyClass> e : myHashMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getValue().getLabel());
}
```

This produced the output (as expected):

```
foo: foo1, bar: bar1
foo: foo2, bar: bar2
```

Comment: It SHOULD work, that's what I think but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Can you debug the code and see what is actually in the map at the time of execution?